# Visual Studio Code Editor Extension for XML Rendering

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins

I have a a requirement to render xml file in a different perspective in Visual Studio. For example if select xml file as [xml content image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj7R8.png) and open in visual studio, I would like to see the content as [Code editor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1NdT.png).

When I modify content in the code editor it should be able to save as xml file. I'm well aware with the xml tags and order in the xml file and order in the code editor text.

thank you.

I'm new to visual studio plugins, so I'm looking for place to start with.

Comment: use custom editor for the process.